# How polymer increases efficiency of webpage and better than other framework like AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I was going through documentation of polymer project but didn't get to know how it can increase UX and efficiency of website.

Answer (score 3):

Polymer

- allows you to create reusable custom tags that can be used with different UI frameworks (Angular, GWT, ...)
- data binding (`{{ ... }}`)
- event binding(`on-eventName=...`)
- provides polyfills for browsers that don't fully support custom elements
- provides a collection of great ready-to-use components (separate project though https://elements.polymer-project.org/)
- ...